# Remove numbers from a column

Tags: python, pandas

Could you please tell me how to remove numbers from this column?

```
                                C
0                           {virgen, oliva, aceite}
1                        {oliva, extra, 19, virgen}

4             {cítricos, extra, 141, virgen, huevos}
                           ...                     
6096            {estabilizante, celulosa, dextrina}
6097                     {devuelvan, bote, orégano}
6098                         {devolución, días, 30}
```

I have tried with `df['C'] = df['C'].str.replace('\d+', '')` but it does not work.

```
Expected: 
                                    C
0                           {virgen, oliva, aceite}
1                            {oliva, extra, virgen}

4                 {cítricos, extra, virgen, huevos}
                           ...                     
6096            {estabilizante, celulosa, dextrina}
6097                     {devuelvan, bote, orégano}
6098                             {devolución, días}
```

Comment: Is the underlying data in C a set? or a string surrounded by curly brackets?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: print `df['C'].apply(type)` and post the result here

Comment: @PruneI provided dataset and attempt so I do not understand why to downvote the question and ask for closing it.  Manakin: The type is <class 'set'> for each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample:

```
      C
0   {b, c, 5, a}
1   {b, c, d, a}
2   {c, 5, 3, a}
```

Code:

```
for i, e in enumerate(df['C']):
    myl = list(e)
    duplicate = myl.copy()
    for item in myl:
         it = str(item)
         if it.isdigit():
            duplicate.remove(item)
    e = set(duplicate)
    df.at[i,'C']=e

df
```

Output:

```
    C
0   {b, c, a}
1   {b, c, d, a}
2   {c, a}
```